# Dovecot Active:failed because of ssl_cert: can't open file /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem: Permission denied. Why?

Tags: linux, permissions, postfix, ssl, dovecot

Hello I try to follow this Postfix/Dovecot tutorial series:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njiNRppQNJw&list=PLibQjquhfgjjosRrZxlDepXfehDXuQJu_&index=5

When I run dovecot:

```
sudo service dovecot restart
sudo service dovecot status
```

I get: `Active: failed`

Unlike postfix who is active normally.

I tried: `dovecot -F` to see what has failed. (suggested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319151/how-to-start-dovecot)

And it said:

```
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf
line 12: ssl_cert: can't open file /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem: Permission denied
```

I tried to look at the permissions on this file:

```
sudo ls -l /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot/pem
```

And got:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 nov. 21 14:04 /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem -> /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
```

I tried to change those permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 700 /etc/dovecot/private/
```

But it hasn't worked out.

I tried to check if I missed a curly braces while making changes in configurations files.
And so far I haven't found anything wrong.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: what are the permission at `/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem`

Comment: Explore permissions with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld It's a `bash` script.

Comment: @BANJOSA I have no file named /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem

Comment: that's the problem... as per the information you've provided above /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem` is a symbolic link to the file at `/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` .

Comment: @BANJOSA How can I get this /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem file?

Comment: That's the certificate for encryption of your endpoint. you need to request one from a valid certificate authority or you cant use a self signed certificate, but the later might cause issues with the client apps that will connect to that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the information you've provided above `/etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem` is a symbolic link to the file at `/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` . If you don´t have a certificate file in that path it will fail.

To do so:

```
sudo apt-get install ssl-cert
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil
sudo usermod --append --groups ssl-cert yyuu
ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
```

as mentioned here: https://gist.github.com/yyuu/4335041